# Hyperledger Composer: restrict permissions of participants to pinging the network

Tags: permissions, hyperledger-composer, access-control

I have developed a hyperledger composer application with an angular front-end.

Whenever a user signs in, he/she pings the network in order to get his/her id:

```
return this.httpClient.get('/api/system/ping', {withCredentials: true}).toPromise() 
.then(data => {
       //more code
});
```

The problem is that this currently only works whenever the network administrator sends this request.

The reason for this is the following rule in the file permissions.acl:

```
rule NetworkAdminSystem {
    description: "Grant network administrators full access to system resources"
    participant: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin"
    operation: ALL
    resource: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.Network"
    action: ALLOW
}
```

Other participants have (so far) no permissions to any system resources.

In order for "normal" participants to be able to ping the network, I want to write a rule that allows them to ping the network but not more.

That is, when it comes to system resources, the only thing allowed for participants is supposed to be pinging the network.

The thing is I don't know what the "resource" line is supposed to look like in the rule:

```
rule AllParticipantsCanPingNetwork {
  description: "Allow all participants to ping the network (in order to get their participant id)."
  participant: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.Participant"
  operation: READ
  resource: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.???"
  action: ALLOW
}
```

What I'm looking for is something like

```
resource: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.ping"
```

... whereby "org.hyperledger.composer.system.ping", unfortunately, doesn't work.

How can I restrict the rights of participants to pinging the network?
Is there some documentation somewhere on what is contained in the namespace "org.hyperledger.composer.system" ?

---

UPDATE:

I am now provisionally using the following rule(s):

```
// Business Access Control Rules:

    //some rules

    //none of the rules gives participants unrestricted READ access 
    //to the business network, Access rights are always bound to specific conditions 


// System Access Control Rules:


 rule AllParticipantsHaveFullAccessToSystemResources {
    description: "Grant business network administrators full access to system resources"
    participant: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.Participant"
    operation: ALL
    resource: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.**"
    action: ALLOW
}
```

---

I actually wanted to restrict access rights further ... to this end I tried the following set of rules:

```
// Business Access Control Rules:


rule AllParticipantsCanAccessTheNetwork {
   description: "Allow all participants to access the network"
   participant: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.Participant"
   operation: READ
   resource: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.Network"
   action: ALLOW
}

rule AllParticipantsCanUseTransactionsAffectingARegistry {
  description: "Allow all participants to use transactions affecting a registry"
  participant: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.Participant"
  operation: ALL
  resource: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.RegistryTransaction"
  action: ALLOW
}

rule NetworkAdministratorsCanUpdateAndDeleteTheNetwork {
    description: "Grant network administrators the right to update and delete the network"
    participant: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin"
    operation: UPDATE, DELETE
    resource: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.Network"
    action: ALLOW
}

rule NetworkAdministratorsCanIssueIdentity {
    description: "Grant network administrators the right to issue an identity"
    participant: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin"
    operation: ALL
    resource: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.IssueIdentity"
    action: ALLOW
}
```

However, this was not enough to send transactions etc.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should work:

in your 'normal ACLs' (for the business network itself - change namespace accordingly - example below):

```
rule readBusiness {
    description: "ACL to connect to the business network"
    participant: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.Participant"
    operation: READ
    resource: "org.acme.mynetwork.*"
    action: ALLOW
}
```

and before the System ACLs:

```
rule ReadNetwork {
    description: "Allow all participants to read network"
    participant: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.Participant"
    operation: READ
    resource: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.Network"
    action: ALLOW
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer ... However, the "readBusiness" rule would give all participants READ access to all other participants and all assets in the business network ... I have developed another solution that avoids that (see UPDATE to my post) ... I would like to restrict access rights even more ... but my approach to this (see UPDATE in post) did not work